# How to get bigger images in News Feed when sharing a link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

I have a page that uses the Facebook Feed and Share dialog. I read on this page of documentation that there is a way to get bigger images into the news feed, rather than the typical thumbnail. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#images

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong but my image never appears to be in the larger format. Its always the tiny thumbnail. Here is the code I have. Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

At first I thought my share.jpg image was too big (it was around 1900x1200) so I sized it down to the min specs that Facebook said to use (1200x630) and I still end up with the tiny thumbnail.

This is the FB.ui function that I have..

```
$(".facebook").bind("click", function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  //link: encodeURIComponent(shareURL),
  link: shareURL,
  caption: 'An example caption',
  picture: 'http://www.example.com/beta/share.jpg'
 }, function(response){});  
});
```

Here's what I have on the page right after `<body>`

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//www.example.com/beta/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

  };


  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out. Looks like the bigger image only works on mobile and the new News Feed (which I still don't have.. WTF? LOL)